# How to teach/learn physics - reference request

Tags: soft-question, education, specific-reference

I remember reading a paper (or a transcript of a talk) which describes the process of learning/teaching physics as a landing on a planet. In order to find a suitable place to land, you need to orbit the planet a couple of times and then gently land. Similar with physics, you should learn the same subject a couple of times, over and over again, each time with a different degree of sophistication.

Does anybody recognize the paper I'm talking about?

Comment: This isn't specific to physics. It applies to essentially every aspect of life.